# BelongsToMany Is Not supported for hybrid query constraints - mongodb laravel

Tags: laravel, mongodb, laravel-5

I'm getting below error in my laravel application getting `belongsToMany` relationship data in the repository. The application only has MongoDB database only. no hybrid with MySQL or any other.

```
 message    "BelongsToMany Is Not supported for hybrid query constraints!"
    exception   "Exception"
    file    "/var/www/backend/vendor/jenssegers/mongodb/src/Jenssegers/Mongodb/Helpers/QueriesRelationships.php"
    line    115
```

Repository code is like below.

```
$moduleInfo = $this->page->whereHas('section', function ($q) use ($module_id) {
            $q->whereHas('chapters', function ($r) use ($module_id) {
                $r->whereHas('modules', function ($s) use ($module_id) {
                    $s->where('_id', $module_id);
                });
            });
        })
            ->with([
                'section' => function ($q) {
                    $q->with([
                        'chapters' => function ($r) {
                            $r->with('modules');
                        }
                    ]);
                }
            ])
            ->get()
            ->toArray();
```

in Page Model

```
public function section()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany( 'App\Models\Section', 'page_id', 'page_ids' );
    }
```

I'm using jenssegers/mongodb package to connect mongo DB and
laraval version is 5.6
jenssegers/mongodb version is 3.4

Data seems fine. Does anyone know the reason for this issue?

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: @Svetoslav sorry. update the question

Comment: You are using nosql, so you should use methods of nosql such as aggregate provided in mongodb documentation, also  If you want to define custom keys for your relation, set second parameter to null(for jenssegers 3.4), it would look like `return $this->belongsToMany( 'App\Models\Section', null, 'page_id', 'page_ids' );`

Comment: see here https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/tree/v3.4.0#relations

Comment: @bhucho Thanks for comment but issue is still there.

Comment: the issue will not solve unless you use nosql methods, read mongo docs, use $match, $groups along with aggregate, you need to change the method, complex queries will not work with sql methods, see [Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)

Comment: If you could provide some example how your collection looks like for the models then only we can help you